# Synonym [scikit-image] vs. [skimage] (or removal of the latter)

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

As seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321075/python-how-to-change-shape-of-the-output-of-skimage-resize), users are already tagging both ([scikit-image](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scikit-image/synonyms), [skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/skimage/synonyms)), leading to exactly the same library.

The official name of this [lib](http://scikit-image.org/) is `scikit-image` and the description of tag `skimage` also uses that name!

The confusion / reason for this duplicate is probably the import-style of scikit-image like:

```
from skimage import data, io, filters
...
```

This source of confusion is exactly the same for `scikit-learn` and `sklearn` which are already synonyms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, [Tonechas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6160119/tonechas) suggested this synonym back in late March of this year, but it never got enough votes to get approved because (A) nobody (to within rounding error) knows about the tag synonyms feature, and (B) there aren't enough users with sufficient reputation in a small tag like that to vote on synonyms anyway.

Anyway, this is an obvious thing to do, and, as you mentioned, it has already been done for [scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) ← [sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sklearn), so you and Tonechas's wishes have now been granted.

I merged the tags and created a synonym: [scikit-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-image) ← [skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skimage)

If you really think a synonym is inappropriate, and the [skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skimage) tag should just die, then please let me know. It's trivial to remove it. But as long as it's unambiguous what [skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skimage) might refer to, there's no harm in keeping the synonym. It'll just help ensure that, no matter what people try to tag their question, they'll get the correct tag on it.

Comment: Yeah, i had to see that i'm unable to vote there. Thanks! Being consistent, i also like the non-removal (as with scikit-learn).